# cannot convert from 'object' to 'decimal'

Tags: c#, types

Basically I have a list:

```
 List<Decimal> SortOrders = new List<Decimal>();
```

And a DataRow.
I wan to compare whether the list contains an item from a control.
But I got an exception,

> cannot convert from "Object " to "decimal

```
DataRow dr = dataSetSomething.Tables[0].NewRow();
...
dr["SortOrder"] = Convert.ToDecimal(numericOrder.Value);// works fine here
if (SortOrders.Contains(dr["SortOrder"]))// exception here, Why?
{
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: The indexer `dr["SortOrder"]` is returning `object` no matter the underlying type. Do this instead: `var sortOrder = Convert.ToDecimal(numericOrder.Value); if (SortOrders.Contains(sortOrder))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `dr["SortOrder"]` is `Object`.

Any type in .NET *is* an object (as all types inherit from `Object`, directly or through the inheritance chain), so assigning a `decimal` to an `object` is fine.

The opposite is not true - not all `object`s are `decimal`.

You need to *cast* in order to get the expected behaviour:

```
 if (SortOrders.Contains((decimal)dr["SortOrder"]))
```

(which will throw an exception if the underlying type is not a `decimal`).

Answer (score 2):

Because the type of `dr["SortOrder"]` is `object`, even if you put a `decimal` in there. If you know it's actually a decimal, you can cast it:

```
if (SortOrders.Contains((decimal)dr["SortOrder"]))
```